# Ubuntu-touch facebook notifications are not received

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, facebook

I dont receive any facebook notification in my Aquarius e4,5. Access to facebook account is allowed in my phone. Is there necessary allow anything on facebook page or is there any known bug?
Second problem is that other notifications (e.g. telegram) are working without notification sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu Touch development channel on my Nexus 4 and I've never had Facebook notifications come through. I don't believe this is a bug per se, but I do believe we'll need to wait until there's a native app for Facebook notifications.